# Move part of string inside the anchor tag

Tags: php

I have a string that is generated via a function.

```
$string = function();
```

It generates something like:

```
$string = '<ul><li><a href="">Test</a>(10)</li>';
```

My question is, how do I move `(10)` part into the end of the anchor tag, so we have:

```
$string = '<ul><li><a href="">Test (10)</a></li>';
```

I want to do this to all anchor tags in the list items.

What's the appropriate PHP approach?

Comment: Change the function.

Comment: do changes in your function itself.share that function here, may be you get help

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I can't change the function. It is generated by a core WordPress function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP would change the function if he could. =D

Comment: You can use [PHP's convenient string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php). How about you try to toss up a function, see if you can get it to work. If not, show us your approach and tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't used WordPress, but I've used other systems and I'm pretty sure you *can* customise core functions, although you'll need to make notes and patch them again when you update the software (in my case, MediaWiki)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's easy for me to change the core files of WP, but this is client work and it's unethical because things will break for them as soon as they update. :)

Comment: @domdom Please post an answer demonstrating this.

Comment: My point was that you could probably come up with such code yourself instead of asking us to write it. But it doesn't matter now, Mahipal already provided you with a solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`srt_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function for your string variable like below:

```
if(strpos($string,"</a>")) {
    $string = str_replace('</a>',' ', $string);
    // output <ul><li><a href="">Test'(10)</li>
    echo $string = str_replace('</li>','</a></li>', $string);
    // output <ul><li><a href="">Test (10)</a></li>
}
```

Comment: This is a *very* interesting approach. Is there any way I can make a "check" before I do the `str_replace()`? There are a few `<li>` items that doesn't have anchor tags inside them.

Comment: This will break unless if **all** of your list tags have a tags inside them. There needs to be a check prior to running the str_replace function...

Comment: yes you can pre check if anchor is exist using strpos() or strstr() functions check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php if position found then perform replace function other just skip it.

Comment: Can you kindly update your answer with the strpos() or strstr() approach?

Comment: please approve answer if this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

Using [HTML DOM](https://eval.in/830865) you can change/modify element values.

For e.g.,

```
<?php
    $string = '<ul><li><a href="test.php">Test</a>(10)</li></ul>';

    echo $string; // Old strings.

    $dom_document = new DOMDocument();

    $dom_document->loadHTML($string);

    $new_string = "";
    foreach($dom_document->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $ul){ // For all ul.
        $new_string .= "<ul>";
        foreach($ul->childNodes as $li){ // For all li.
            $new_string .= "<li>";
            $i=0;
            foreach($li->childNodes as $a){
                if(isset($a->attributes[0]->value)){
                    $href = $a->attributes[0]->value;
                }
                if($i===0){
                    $new_string .= '<a href="'.$href.'">';
                }
                $new_string .= $a->nodeValue;
                $i++;
            }
            $new_string .= "</a>";
            $new_string .= "</li>";
        }
        $new_string .= "</ul>";
    }

    echo $new_string; // New generated strings.
?>
```

See [Fiddle](https://eval.in/830865).